# Sync images with Slick Carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, slick.js

Basically I'm using https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ for this

I've read the Slick documentation and indeed there is a sync option but available only with another slide.
Is it possible to link images to show with the slide ?

Thank you in advance.

JS code of the slide :

```
$(function(){ 
        
$('.center').slick({
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: "0px",
    slidesToShow: 8,
    arrows:false,
    autoplay:false,
    infinite:false,
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
          arrows: false,
          centerMode: true,
          centerPadding: '40px',
          slidesToShow: 3
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
          arrows: false,
          centerMode: true,
          centerPadding: '40px',
          slidesToShow: 1
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  
});
```

Comment: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/1563 this link may help you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `afterChange()` and `beforeChange()` events to trigger any JavaScript that you want. For instance, you can write a function to toggle other images to show like this:

**HTML**

```html
<img id="image0" class="hero-image" src="..." />
<img id="image1" class="hero-image" src="..." />
<img id="image2" class="hero-image" src="..." />
```

**CSS**

```css
// Hide all images to start
.hero-image {
  display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```js
// Show the current slide's corresponding image after the slide is shown
$('.center').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
  $('.hero-image').hide();
  $(`image${currentSlide}`).show();
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much !!